# IBM 3534-1RU SAN HUB

Tags: storage-area-network, fibre-channel

I was given an IBM 3534-1RU SAN HUB and I realized that it isn't a fibre hub that would do TCP/IP!

So what could I use this for?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have FC gear, not much. Ebay?

Answer (score 0):

It is used to connect Fiber Channel HBAs to a FC SAN enclosure.